# Помогите с подключением плагина placeholder!

Tags: javascript, html, плагин, вёрстка

Нужно чтоб работал placeholder в ie.
Скачал тут плагин:
https://github.com/dciccale/placeholder-enhanced

На страницу с формой вставил такой код в конец, и ничего не работает в ие. Помогите кто знает как, что я не дописал там. Вот сайт сам - http://websterjoy.tk/contacts.html

Comment: в webkit работает, мб плагин не поддерживает осла?

Comment: в webkit и без плагина placeholder работает. Это я для IE <=9 специально поставил плагин.

Comment: спасибо вам!

Comment: Удачи! Поставьте же плагин наконец на сайт ;)

Comment: Нда... Давно живу, многое видел... Но чтобы js-скрипты с гитхаба подключали в виде сохраненной html-страницы - это что-то новенькое. Поржал, спасибо...)

Comment: Ну простите, думала разберется) Плагин можно скачать здесь - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я для этих целей ставила плагин по ссылке http://rawgithub.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/master/jquery.placeholder.js

Пример использования - http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Вызывается скрипт так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
});
```

В `Input`'ах пропишите `placeholder="ваш плейсхолдер"`.

Плагин в IE <=9 замечательно работает.

Answer (score 1):

Проще сделай так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:text, textarea, input:password").each(function() {
    if (this.value == '')
      this.value = this.title;
  });
  $("input:text, textarea, input:password").focus(function() {
    if (this.value == this.title)
      this.value = '';
  });
  $("input:text, textarea, input:password").blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '')
      this.value = this.title;
  });
  $("input:image, input:button, input:submit").click(function() {
    $(this.form.elements).each(function() {
      if (this.type =='text' || this.type =='textarea' || this.type =='password') {
        if (this.value == this.title && this.title != '') {
          this.value = '';
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

И просто в input и textarea прописывай не placeholder, а title. Или просто в этом коде поменяй везде title на placeholder, если именно он тебе нужен.